# What is the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2/F$ where $F =a[1,1]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

What is the quotient space $\mathbb{R}^2/F$ where $F =a[1,1]$?
How do you find a basis of it? What is a good way to think of it in mind?

Comment: What is $a$?  [...]

Comment: Any number in the field R

Comment: So is $F$ the space spanned by the vector $[1,1]$?

Comment: That's what I guessed arther

Comment: If you meant $\;F:=\text{Span}_{\Bbb R}\left\{\binom11\right\}=\left\{ a\binom11\;/\;a\in\Bbb R\right\}\;$ ,then one has to be a little more proper to write mathematics *and expect* others will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you meant the quotient space $\;U:=\Bbb R^2/F\;$ , then as $\;\dim U=1\;$ , you only need one non-zero vector to span it, and since

$$\binom10\notin F\implies \left\{\binom10+F\right\}\;\;\text{is a base for the quotient space}$$

Comment: (1,0)' is a vector and F is a vector space. What does it mean by (1,0)' + F?

Comment: @user1559897, that is a left coset, and that's how elements in a *quotient space* look like...unless you meant **other thing** by that notation $\;\Bbb R^2/F\;$, which is the usual way to denote a quotient linear space.